# Redirect IP address to domain name - not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying fix ip canonicalization by redirecting the a certain ip to domain name. I have followed a number of solutions but none of them seems to be working at all.
.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.1$ [NC,OR] //ip address
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea why this issue os not fixed?!

Comment: @anubhava if i tried entering the ip address in the url it gives a blank page with the word pageok just written in it. I need it to redirect to my domain name.

Comment: @anubhava  Why do you suggest then?! I was running some seo checkups and it failed at the ip canonicalization test stating I should the above rules in order to fix but that didn't happen.

Comment: Shared hosting co. usually don't let you control IP based URLs since there are multiple domains sharing same IP.

Comment: @anubhava Wouldn't that affect my SEO performance. It states that this could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes the site under both ip and domain name.

Comment: so would there be a problem if this issue was skipped?! Aren't there any other solutions?!

Comment: No, I am not aware of any solution for this. For me it is not even a problem. You can safely ignore this.